# swap text strings which includes special character with sed or perl -e

Tags: perl, shell, sed

I want to swap a text string surrounded by [] to the end of this line.
My input string:

```
[xyz] <Rest of line> \n
```

and I want to swap it to

```
<Rest of line> [xyz] \n
```

The special characters does not like me ;-) I tried this

```
perl -e s/([.*])(.*)/\2\1/g
```

Comment: This ain't difficult – it just needs a substitution regex with two captures. What have you tried so far to solve this problem?

Comment: @user2798782 Add that to your question using the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18914747/edit) button.

Comment: @user2798782 You were close.  Escaping `[` and `]` should make it work.

Comment: @user2798782: You're close, just escape the square brackets `\[` and `\]` and use `$2$1` instead of `\2\1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you used the one-liner

```
 perl -e s/([.*])(.*)/\2\1/g
```

This has the following problems:

You didn't quote the regex. Therefore, characters like `*` can be interpreted by the shell as a glob. Use single quotes:

```
perl -e 's/([.*])(.*)/\2\1/g'
```

Now, inside regexes, `[` and `]` are special: They enclose *character classes*. The charclass `[.*]` means: match either a literal `.` or an `*`. To make the brackets non-special, escape them.

```
perl -e 's/(\[.*\])(.*)/\2\1/g'
```

Now this regex means match an opening bracket, match as many characters as possible, and then a closing bracket. After that, as many characters as possible. This ends up matching up until the last `]` in the first group. E.g. the input `[foo][bar]baz` would be `baz[foo][bar]`.

We will change the regex so it means: “match a opening bracket, then as many non-closing-bracket characters as possible, then a closing bracket. …”:

```
perl -e 's/(\[[^\]]*\])(.*)/\2\1/g'
```

The next problem is that you haven't given perl anything to match. If you want to apply this regex to each line in your input, add the `-p` option. Now:

```
perl -pe's/(\[[^\]]*\])(.*)/\2\1/g'
```

Now only a few minor problems remain. The input

```
abc def
[abc] def
```

outputs

```
abc def
 def[abc]
```

We can add another capture for the whitespace between the parts. We should also use the variables `$1` etc in the substitution part. And the `/g` option is useless here. Now we get:

```
perl -pe's/^(\[[^\]]*\])(\s*)(.*)/$3$2$1/'
```

Which outputs:

```
abc def
def [abc]
```

Comment: I was writing:
cat test_in.txt | perl -pe's/^(\[[^\]]*\])(\s*)(.*)/$3$2$1/' > test.txt
But the test.txt == test_in.txt
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @user2798782 backslashes are important! If you add those where present in my answer, everything works as expected. (Although you should remove the useless `cat` and specify the input like `<test_in.txt` instead). Also, I assume that the bracket bit must be at the start of the line – no whitespace allowed before that. If this isn't the case, swap `^` for `^\s*\K` or something.

Comment: one line of the input file looks like:
[foo_test_1] "C:\\work\\foo.c", line 24: warning (dcc:1516): parameter bar is never used

Comment: I have a problem with my environment. I'm using Windows cmd shell + Cygwin. In a bash everything is fine.
Does anyone have here a solution? Script have to run in a windows cmd-box.

Comment: @user2798782 I tested my stuff on bash. On cmd.exe, you should use double quotes instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
echo "[xyz] <Rest of line>" | awk -F\] '{print $2,$1FS}'
 <Rest of line> [xyz]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $string = ("[xyz] <Rest of line> \n");
my ($match1, $match2) = ($string =~ /(\[\w+\])(.*)/);
print "$match2 $match1\n";
```

Output:

```
<Rest of line>  [xyz]
```